# linking to post outside the loop

Tags: posts, loop, id, shortlink

Is there an easy way to link to a specific page/post outside the loop? I used the `get_permalink()` code as follows.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 164 ); ?>/post-slug/"> </a>
```

But this meant that I had to get the post ID from the Shortlink in the Admin for the post I wanted and then append the slug to it. Is there a better way to get the post ID of the post I am looking for, without using the loop?

My permalinks are set up to use the post name so this seemed to work.

Comment: You should not have to append the post-slug to the get_permalink function. Check the codex - if the permalink is not returning anything - make sure the ID is correct. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

Comment: I am still really confused here. You are correct that I don't need to append the post-slug here. My question is can I get the address for the post without knowing the ID? And if I need the ID, can I get it without being in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [`get_page_by_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) function?

You can use like `<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_title('My Post Title')); ?>`

Comment: +1 not for the easiness the OP asks for, but for uniqueness.

Comment: The drawback is that this will [run an additional query](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3550) and one that may be avoidable.

Comment: I am afraid that this didn't work for me. The get_permalink returned the address of the current post whereas I wanted an address of a different post. My permalinks are set up to use the post name and I want a link for a different post.

Comment: I want to be able to jump around the website to different pages and posts regardless of where I am on the site. What is the easiest way to link to a specific post or page?

Comment: How did you use the get_permalink function? Are you linking to a post? I forgot to mention, if you are linking to a post you have to do `get_page_by_title('Title', OBJECT, 'post')`

Comment: I am using the get_permalink function outside a loop. I am linking to a specific post in one case and to a page in another. I don't understand the syntax you are showing me here in the get_page_by_title. What is OBJECT and what is 'post'. I just need some good examples of how this is used and did not find it in the codex. thanks.